# call multiple times client side callback function in asp .net in devexpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

How do I call multiple times client side callback function in asp .net in devexpress.

Here is the pageload event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsCallback)
        return;
    //Creating a reference of Client side Method, that is called after callback on server
    String cbReference = Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "arg","ReceiveServerData", "");

    //Putting the reference in the method that will initiate Callback
    String callbackScript = "function CallServer(arg, context) {" +cbReference + "; }";

    //Registering the method
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"CallServer", callbackScript, true);
}

public void RaiseCallbackEvent(String eventArgument)
{
    DateTime dob = Convert.ToDateTime(eventArgument);
    DateTime Today = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan ts = Today - dob;
    DateTime Age = DateTime.MinValue + ts;

    int Years = Age.Year - 1;
    int Months = Age.Month - 1;
    int Days = Age.Day - 1;
    result = Years.ToString();
}

public string GetCallbackResult()
{
    return result;
}
```

Here is the javascript function:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function InitiateCallBack(value) {
        CallServer(value, '');
    }

    // Called after the server side processing is done
    function ReceiveServerData(arg, context) {
        $("#MainContent_ASPxtxtAge_I").val(arg);
    }
</script>
```

Here only the single time call back occurs, but how can I call multiple times from multiple buttons?

I am using devexpress along with asp .net c#.
Any suggestions regarding this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a simple function, not a callback itself, you can call that function from any Button this way

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnOther" runat="server" Text="Function" AutoPostBack="false" 
                                      ClientSideEvents-Click="function(s, e) { InitiateCallBack(value); }">
                                  </dx:ASPxButton>
```

Comment: If i declare more then one function in client side every function hit in RaiseCallbackEvent  code behind function.

Comment: I am sorry @asasasaa I don't undestand what you mean